# how to expand all child nodes inside one parent node/group element on custom get context menu items in Ag grid Enterprise version

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using the enterprise version of ag grid. I have a custom context menu and inside there are many parent nodes and inside each parent node, there are nested child nodes.Currently I can expand it by the parent level, but don't know how to expand all child nodes at the same time. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
{
    name: 'Expand All',
    action() {
      params.api.forEachNode((node, index) => {
        if (node.group && node.groupData['ag-Grid-AutoColumn'] === 
            params.value) {
          node.setExpanded(true);
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue with AG Grid, Unfortunately I couldn't find anything useful in AG Grid API to achieve this functionality. So I had to achieve it in this way:

```
name: 'Expand All',
    action: () => {
      let totalChildNodes = 0;
      let checkCount = 0;
      params.api.forEachNode((node, index) => {
        if (node.group && node.groupData['ag-Grid-AutoColumn'] === params.value) {
          totalChildNodes = node.allChildrenCount;
          node.expanded = true;
        }
        if (totalChildNodes > 0 && checkCount <= totalChildNodes) {
          checkCount++;
          node.expanded = true;
        }
      });
      params.api.onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed();
    }
```

What the above code does is it checks the clicked node and get it's child count and then expand all its child nodes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a helper method to define child nodes like this:

```
 getChildNodes(clickedNode:RowNode):RowNode[]{

    let haveEnteredChildZone:boolean = false;
    let haveLeftChildZone:boolean = false;
    let childNodes:RowNode[] = [];

    this.gridApi.forEachNode((n=>{
      if(n.id === clickedNode.id){haveEnteredChildZone = true; return;}
      if(haveEnteredChildZone && n.level === clickedNode.level){        haveLeftChildZone = true; return;}
      if(haveEnteredChildZone && !haveLeftChildZone){
        childNodes.push(n)
      }
    }))

    return childNodes;
  }
```

The code below makes use of this helper method to then expand the child nodes if their level was sufficiently deep for my requirements:

```
drillRowToLevel(params, level) {

    let childNodes:RowNode[] = this.getChildNodes(params.node); //get child nodes
    childNodes.forEach(n=>{
        this.gridApi.setRowNodeExpanded(n,n.level<level)  //set child nodes expanded
    })
    this.gridApi.setRowNodeExpanded(params.node,params.node.level < level); //expand self
    this.gridApi.onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed();  //enact the expansion changes
  }
```

You could simplify this second method by hard-coding level to your highest level to expand all child nodes.